# Setting Some TextView's Text

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

In my Project , I have 80 TextViews.
I should set their text from 1 to 80 once project runs , and they dont need to be changed in future.
Except TxtViews , I have some other things in my Layout, the TextViews are under ImagesViews. actually I have 80 imagesViews and under them are 80 TextViews. I want to set text of textViews from 1 to 80 dynamically.
I know I can do it in my layout.xml ,
but its really time consuming.
is there any way to do that by code?
for example with a for cycle or something like that?

Comment: u can use for loop ? or post ur code the way u hv done

Comment: Do your `TextView`s have IDs? If they do, you can do it. But keep in mind that it will require calling `findViewById(id)` many times and this operation is very time-consuming. Please reconsider setting the values statically in your XML.

Comment: You should write a separate simple program to generate the layout.xml file

Comment: are all your textviews in one parent layout?

Comment: Create your own custom TextView.

Comment: All my TextViews are in One parent Layout and they all have IDs.but I dont want to set their text manually!in that way,I MUST do it 80 times!!!

Comment: Yes, you would do it 80 times **once**, which is infinitely better than having your app do it 80 times **every time you open it**. But, if you really want to do this, the `ListView` approach is the way to go.

Comment: You really should edit your question... Put some code, and inform the things you said on the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewGroup suitable for your needs in the layout, for example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Then you create you TextView instances programatically, and add them to the LinearLayout, like this:

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setText("text" + i);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
```

Optionally, you can add tags or whatever to locate them again. Alternatively just iterate over the layouts subviews.

Comment: Except TxtViews , I have some other things in my code , so I cannot use that I think.

Comment: Well, It's a far more maintainable solution, what are your constraints?

Comment: the TextViews are under ImagesViews. actually I have 80 imagesViews witch under them are 80 TextViews. I want to set text of textViews from 1 to 80 dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that 80 Textview fixed then you should take listview for that.

Listview **Benefit**

- Memory management automatically
- Listview manage indexing

Answer (score 0):

If they share the same layout, except for the text, and could be displayed as a list, you could use an ArrayAdapter and pass the values from code.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: Dear Tragalunas , I dont want to write numbers from 1 to 80.in this way , I should do the same thing.

Comment: You can also write your array from a loop: string[] testArray = new string[80];

for (int i = 1; i < testArray.length; i++) {  
    testArray[i]=String.valueOf(i);
}

Comment: Corrections for the above code: String[] testArray = new String[80]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) { 
   testArray[i]=String.valueOf(i+1); }

Answer (score 0):

If your `TextView`s are declared on the xml, wrap them on another view so you can reference it on the java code later, then simply use a `for`.

Something like:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.your_wrapper);

for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount(); i++) {
    View nChild = ((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(i);
    TextView tv = (TextView) nChild;
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
}
```

If not, you can simply create them dynamically inside your java code, and append them to a layout like `LinearLayout`.

Example:

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:id="@+id/linear"
/>
```

**Java code**

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

for (int i = 1; i <= 80; i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this); // Assuming you're inside an Activity.
    int count = ll.getChildCount();
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));

    ll.addView(tv, count, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

---

**EDIT:** But truly, you should use [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for that if your values are not going to change.

You can read more about `RecyclerView` [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/), and on `ListView` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

---

**Second edit:** From what you're saying on your comments, you REALLY should be using `ListView` instead of your current design. The solutions above and from the other answers won't work at all for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below example,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout linearLayout ;
ScrollView scrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewActivityMain);
}

private void populateTextViews() {

    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    //add all textViews here
    for(int i=0; i < 80; i++){
        TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
        myTextView.setText("My TextView "+i);
        myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        linearLayout.addView(myTextView);
    }

    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
}
}
```

Don't forget to put that scrollView in your xml.
Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Except TxtViews , I have some other things in my code,
the TextViews are under ImagesViews. actually I have 80 imagesViews witch under them are 80 TextViews. I want to set text of textViews from 1 to 80 dynamically.

Comment: For showing so many images in a single screen, I think here you are looking for ListView/RecyclerView, otherwise the app would crash if we do it the way as above

Comment: checkout this link, I am sure this is what you are looking for...http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/